# Load exported model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a TensorFLow model trained on a GPU machine. Next, I need to export it and deploy on CPU only production machine.

I have used export as described in [MNIST export example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_export.py). Saver object was initialized above.

```
with graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(), sharded=True)

...


export_path =  'resnet34_rmsprop_wd1e-1/saves/'
print('Exporting trained model to %s' % export_path)
init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_tables(), name='init_op')
model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
model_exporter.init(sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
                            init_op=init_op,
                            default_graph_signature=exporter.classification_signature(input_tensor=inference_images,
                                                                                      classes_tensor=inference_class,
                                                                                      scores_tensor=inference_predictions),
                            named_graph_signatures={'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({'images': inference_images}),
                                                    'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({'class': inference_class, 'predictions': inference_predictions})})
model_exporter.export(export_path, tf.constant(1), sess)
print('Done exporting!')
```

Next, I am trying to load saved model with:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('assets/saved_model/export.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, 'assets/saved_model/export')
```

And what I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_test_classifier.py", line 4, in <module>
...
line 33, in __initialize_session__
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('assets/saved_model/export.meta')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1711, in import_meta_graph
read_meta_graph_file(meta_graph_or_file), clear_devices)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1598, in _import_meta_graph_def
input_graph_def, name="", producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 258, in import_graph_def
op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: u'SaveV2'
```

What is the reason of the error and how it could be fixed?

Also, maybe there are other ways of importing TensorFlow models to Python?

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to use TensorFlow serving to load the exported model: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic

This error says 'SaveV2' is not found in the registered ops. So you can try to upgrade TensorFlow to latest version.

Comment: I have tried updating TF to the latest version. It did not help, still getting "KeyError: u'SaveV2'"